# The 404 page works with problems in .NET7

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

i make 404page IN .NET 7 with this code

`app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error404");`

My problem is that when I enter the URL example.com/contactus/form/gdhsgdg, which does not exist, the 404 page does not show up. However, when I enter the URL example.com/contactus/formdsjhdshg, which also does not exist, the 404 page shows up.

I want the 404 page to be displayed by entering an address like example.com/contactus/form/gdhsgdg.

Comment: Do you mean you want to show a page when you entering a wrong url?

Comment: @QingGuo Yes, I have done this now, but it does not show up for all incorrect paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want below?

In controller:

```
        [Route("Error/404")]
        public IActionResult Error404(int code)
        {

            return View("Error404");
        }
```

Error404 view:

```
this  is error 404
```

Program.cs:

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
```

Update:

Try to add a route attribute:

```
       [Route("/contactus/form/")]
        public IActionResult form()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

result:

[image]

Comment: This is the address where my form is located:
https://localhost:44395/contactus/form

But if the address changes to:
https://localhost:44395/contactus/form/fsdfss

The 404 page is not displayed.

Comment: @Samuter  Because we set route value as "pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}" So the "fsdfss" will be set in id, then `localhost:44395/contactus/form/fsdfss`  not a new address, the 404 page is not displayed.

Comment: So, if I remove that id, there won't be any issues?

In some pages, there might be a need for an id.

Comment: @Samuter Yes you are right. In some pages, there might be a need for an id. In that case how about  add id like:`https://localhost:7288/home/index?id=1` ?

Comment: Well, of course, it's possible that in another page we might need an id. Right?

For example:
https://localhost:44395/product/samsungmobile/s56454

Am I Right?

Comment: @Samuter You are right. So now we just add a route at contactus/form, then  we don't change   route  pattern,  it's possible that in another page we might need an id. Please see my update.

Comment: @Samuter  What's  your route? Did my answer help you solve the problem?  If not, could you please follow up to let me know?

Comment: No, currently the Area route is giving a 404 error, but the previous route is working correctly. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can resolve that?

Comment: Why can't I tag you?